# Item from listview saved state of previously item

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am a new android developer and I need your help.
I created a simple listview. I add items in this listview through the keyboard.
Moreover I add action on item. When user click "OK" the app will be strike out text and set background green.

But when I add the next item,I see that it applies that strike out and background option from previously item.

Can you advise me what I need to do in this situation? How to improve it?

My Code:

```
package com.example.boytsov.foodbasketapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Boytsov on 23.07.2015.
 */
public class ProductList extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {
    EditText myText;
    ListView lvMain;
    ArrayList<String> catnames;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Button button;
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.productlist);

        lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
        myText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        catnames= new ArrayList<String>();
        // создаем адаптер
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames);

        // присваиваем адаптер списку
        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lvMain.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        // Прослушиваем нажатия клавиш

        button.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button :

                catnames.add(0, myText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                myText.setText("");
                myText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                myText.setPaintFlags(0);

        break;

            }

    }



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + i + ", id = "
                + l);
        TextView textview= (TextView) view;
        if (textview.getPaintFlags() != 16){
            textview.setPaintFlags(16);
            textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#77dd77"));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Куплено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else {
            textview.setPaintFlags(0);
            textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        catnames.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Удалено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onItemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
                + id);
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

every listview item has its own `R.id.editText` so having one global `myText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);` does not work.

Instead you have to find the edit in the onClick handler

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button : {
                // EditText myText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                TextView myText = (TextView) view;
                catnames.add(0, myText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                myText.setText("");
                myText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                myText.setPaintFlags(0);
            }
        break;

            }

    }
```

[Update 28.7.2015]
Your adapter is using [android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) :

```
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames);
```

wich does not have an EditText  with id R.id.editText. therefore you get an exception.

simple_list_item_1 is a textview. using

```
  TextView myText = (TextView) view;
```

might work

Comment: But now I have the following problem:

07-28 16:25:57.979  27233-27233/com.example.boytsov.foodbasketapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.boytsov.foodbasketapp, PID: 27233
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.boytsov.foodbasketapp.ProductList.onClick(ProductList.java:58)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)